# Puppeteer - How do I click on a element that shares a class with other elements?

Tags: java, puppeteer

I'm trying to user Puppeteer to click on this element from the code below.

The page has two links and I would like to click on the first one.
`hyperlinkclick` is the class for both, no Id.

`await page.click('*[class="hyperlinkclick"]' );` didn't work as it did for other pages.

I also tried the full path `#ScrollingTable > .summaryrow > .summarydata > span > .hyperlinkclick`

```
<tbody style="overflow: auto; height: 36px;" id="ScrollingTable">
    <tr class="summaryrow">
    <td class="summarydata"><span>All</span></td><td align="right" class="summarydata"><span><a class="." onclick="NewReport('wcreports.WkstaListAll','','&amp;grp=AccountId&amp;sum=all&amp;nogrp2=yes')">1,089</a></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="regularrow">
    <td class="datadata"><span>
                        (Unassigned)
                    </span></td><td align="right" class="datadata"><span><a class="hyperlinkclick" onclick="NewReport('wcreports.WkstaListAll',&quot;&quot;,'&amp;sum=all')">1,089</a></span></td>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Does `await page.click('.hyperlinkclick');` work? If not, please provide more details or maybe a link to the live page if possible.

Comment: Seems that the issue is that I have a frameset in the HTML , and puppeteer   isn't able to locate the element